# Event 'after setAt' in google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I have some confusing problem here,

I tried to capture the polyline.getPath lat & lng with this code :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Polyline.getPath() , "set_at" , function(tmpposisi, urutan){


  function index(tmpposisi, urutan){

    for (var i = 0; i < this.getLength(); i++)
    { 
      urutan = i;

    }

    function cek(tmpposisi){
      urutan = this.getAt(tmpposisi);
    }

  }

  console.log(tmpposisi,urutan.toUrlValue(4), data[ Number( tmpposisi) ] );

});
```

but, when I tried to drag the polyline path, the console return the "previous lat & lng" instead of the newest lat & lng. I think the 'getAt' fired at the same time (or before) with 'set_at' fired as mentioned in google maps API documentation.

my question is, how can I get the newest lat & lng from Polyline path ? which is the one after event 'setAt' Triggered ?? or if it's not possible, how can I achieve my purpose with different approach ??

thanks !

Comment: Is the `Polyline` class created by you or just a google maps Polyline class?

Comment: it's google maps Polyline class. thank you for comment, please ask me if my question was'nt clear enough

Comment: 1) You want get all lat/lng or just the latest one?  2) Have you using drawmanager API?

Comment: I want to get lat&lng value from the polyline path that I move.